# windows 7 asp.net mvc RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

i have a problem with asp.net mvc on windows 7... asp.net mvc RC was previously installed and i installed MVC rtm... it says “the project type is not supported by this installation”... is there anyway to register this project type in to visual studio or unregister the rc version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall every ASP.NET MVC installation (in control panel) and reinstall the final 1.0 release. If it didn't help, run Visual Studio command prompt as administrator and run:

```
devenv /resetskippkgs
```

Not sure. Helped me once. I hope that works for you.

Comment: the first suggestion of install and uninstall doesnt work but the second one worked thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You have to install MVC 1.0 even though you may have MVC 2. I did that and it worked for me.
OS Version: Windows 7
IDE: Visual Web Developer 2008 Express